# packaging biom for FreeBSD

Tags: python, biom

I'm working on packaging `biom` (2.1.5) for FreeBSD.

Based on the documentation, I initially had it depending on `pynumpy` and `h5py`, but digging I think it should also depend on:

```
py27-click-6.6
py27-future-0.14.3
py27-pyqi-0.2.0
py27-scipy-0.16.1.
```

Now I'm at the point where running `biom` gives the errors below.  Do you have
suggestions for debugging?  I'm not a python developer, so please be gentle.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/biom", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('biom-format==2.1.5', 'console_scripts', 'biom')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 547, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2720, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2380, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2386, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/biom/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .table import Table
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/biom/table.py", line 188, in <module>
    from future.utils import string_types
ImportError: cannot import name string_types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In future 0.14.3, there is no `string_types` in `future.utils`. (Although it is mentioned in the documentation). Look at the `0.14.x` branch of the [github repo for future](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future).

At the time of writing the current version of the [future module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future) is 0.15.2. So that port needs to be updated before biom will work. I'd suggest to contact the maintainer of that port.